# Change name of parameter in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have project with Map Route (that's all):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and I have method in controller:

```
public ViewResult List(int id = 1)
{
  ...
}
```

and in **List.cshtml**:

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "List", "Product", new { id = i }, null)
```

but i want to change id to page, but not change it in `RouteConfig.cs`, i think that's some attribute which can config my route for action. I want this solution:

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "List", "Product", new { page = i }, null)
```

and

```
[maybe here I can add my specify route?]
public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute routing to override the convention.

First make sure attribute routing is enabled:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();   

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then add appropriate attribute to your controller method, for example:

```
[Route("YourControllerName/List/{page?}")]
public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Question mark makes the page parameter optional.

**If it's a default controller and action**

```
[Route("")]
[Route("YourControllerName/List/{page?}")]
public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
{
    ...
}
```

More about attribute routing can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx